# ZK Framework, Execute MVVM command when all zk components have been loaded

Tags: mvvm, zk, zul

I am working with ZK 8.0.2. I use MVVM pattern. I want execute a view model command when all zk components have been loaded. How I can do?

I annoted by @Init but @Init method is executed before all zk components are loaded. I need execute a view model command when all components (included scripts) are loaded.

I annoted ny @AfterCompose but same behaviour

Comment: Hello Aroniaina, what is the scope to exec the command? Do you want to populate something? If yes, what do you want to populate?

Comment: Scope is `@Scope("desktop")` and YES, i want to populate something

Comment: I want to populate a dual list and a ckeditor

Comment: In this case...you have to bind your elements as usual. If you are in trouble please add some code to the question, please.

Comment: Did you try passing your view in your `afterCompose` and adding a `onAfterRender` eventListener to it ?